Compatibility issue between AMS classes, babel with CJK, and TikZ externalize in LuaTeX
I am experiencing an error while using amsart with babel for CJK support and the TikZ external library in LuaHBTeX. My document setup is as follows:
\documentclass{amsart} % similar error with amsbook, amsproc; works fine with article, book, etc.

\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide{chinese} % similar error with japanese, korean; works fine with english, arabic, etc.

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix = tikz/]

\begin{document}

\tikz{\draw (0, 0) -- (1, 0);}

\end{document}

The following error occurs:

Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'lualatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tikz/output-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{output}\input{output}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'tikz/output-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'tikz/output-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.

I've tried adding \usetikzlibrary{babel} after \usepackage{tikz}, but the error persists.
I am using LuaHBTeX Version 1.18.0. This issue does not occur with pdfTeX or XeTeX.
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
Log:
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024)  (format=lualatex 2024.7.26)  23 SEP 2024 21:29
 system commands enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
**main
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-05-27>
Lua module: luaotfload 2024-02-14 3.28 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2023-07-13 2.76 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended collection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/Invypie/.texlive2024/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2023-12-28.lua" from kpse-resolved path "d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-2023-12-28.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 3.134
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 2
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "C:/Users/Invypie/.texlive2024/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_truetype_file'.
Removing  `luaotfload.glyph_stream' from `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.glyphstream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' in `post_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' in `glyph_info'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload.letterspace_done = 3
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' in `luaotfload.patch_font_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `tracingstacklevels' in `input_level_string'. (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsart.cls
Document Class: amsart 2020/05/29 v2.20.6
\linespacing=\dimen140
\normalparindent=\dimen141
\normaltopskip=\skip49
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from C:/Users/Invypie/.texlive2024/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.gz (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2024/05/23 v2.17q AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip50

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
 (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks17
\ex@=\dimen142
)) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen143
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count192
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 235.
\uproot@=\count193
\leftroot@=\count194
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 398.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \colon on input line 409.
\classnum@=\count195
\DOTSCASE@=\count196
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 495.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 498.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 619.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box52
\strutbox@=\box53
LaTeX Info: Redefining \big on input line 721.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Big on input line 722.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bigg on input line 723.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bigg on input line 724.
\big@size=\dimen144
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 742.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 743.
\macc@depth=\count197
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bmod on input line 904.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pmod on input line 909.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \smash on input line 939.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \relbar on input line 969.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Relbar on input line 970.
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count198
\dotsspace@=\muskip17
\c@parentequation=\count199
\dspbrk@lvl=\count266
\tag@help=\toks18
\row@=\count267
\column@=\count268
\maxfields@=\count269
\andhelp@=\toks19
\eqnshift@=\dimen145
\alignsep@=\dimen146
\tagshift@=\dimen147
\tagwidth@=\dimen148
\totwidth@=\dimen149
\lineht@=\dimen150
\@envbody=\toks20
\multlinegap=\skip51
\multlinetaggap=\skip52
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks21
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2953.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2954.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 397.
 (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)
\copyins=\insert252
\abstractbox=\box54
\listisep=\skip53
\c@part=\count270
\c@section=\count271
\c@subsection=\count272
\c@subsubsection=\count273
\c@paragraph=\count274
\c@subparagraph=\count275
\c@figure=\count276
\c@table=\count277
\abovecaptionskip=\skip54
\belowcaptionskip=\skip55
\captionindent=\dimen151
\thm@style=\toks22
\thm@bodyfont=\toks23
\thm@headfont=\toks24
\thm@notefont=\toks25
\thm@headpunct=\toks26
\thm@preskip=\skip56
\thm@postskip=\skip57
\thm@headsep=\skip58
\dth@everypar=\toks27
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2024/06/26 v24.7 The Babel package
 (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/luababel.def
\bbl@readstream=\read2
\l@dumylang=\language2
Package babel Info: Non-standard hyphenation setup on input line 118.
\l@nohyphenation=\language3
\l@vietnamese=\language4
\l@hebrew=\language5
\babelcatcodetablenum=\catcodetable14
\bbl@pattcodes=\catcodetable15
)
\babel@savecnt=\count278
\U@D=\dimen152
\l@unhyphenated=\language6
 (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/luababel.def
\bbl@attr@locale=\attribute4
)
Package babel Info: You haven't specified a language as a class or package
(babel)             option. I'll load 'nil'. Reported on input line 4269.
 (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/nil.ldf
Language: nil 2024/06/26 v24.7 Nil language
\l@nil=\language7
)) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/locale/zh/babel-chinese.tex
Package babel Info: Importing basic data for chinese
(babel)             from babel-zh.ini. Reported on input line 11.
)
Package babel Info: Hyphen rules for 'chinese' set to \l@nil
(babel)             (\language7). Reported on input line 4.
Inserting `Babel.hyphenate' in `hyphenate'. (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel-ca-chinese.tex) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks28
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen153
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen154
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box55
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)
Package: pgfrcs 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))
Package: pgf 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
 (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
 (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks29
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2024/05/23 v1.4g Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
 (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2023/12/02 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 106.
 (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def
File: luatex.def 2024/04/13 v1.2e Graphics/color driver for luatex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen155
\Gin@req@width=\dimen156
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
 (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks30
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks31
 (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks32
))
\pgf@x=\dimen157
\pgf@y=\dimen158
\pgf@xa=\dimen159
\pgf@ya=\dimen160
\pgf@xb=\dimen161
\pgf@yb=\dimen162
\pgf@xc=\dimen163
\pgf@yc=\dimen164
\pgf@xd=\dimen165
\pgf@yd=\dimen166
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read3
\c@pgf@counta=\count279
\c@pgf@countb=\count280
\c@pgf@countc=\count281
\c@pgf@countd=\count282
\t@pgf@toka=\toks33
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks34
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks35
\pgf@sys@id@count=\count283
 (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-luatex.def
 (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-luatex.def
File: pgfsys-luatex.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
 (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count284
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count285
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2023/11/15 v3.01 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
 (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 274.
 (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1350.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1354.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
 (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen167
\pgfmath@count=\count286
\pgfmath@box=\box56
\pgfmath@toks=\toks36
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks37
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks38
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count287
)) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen168
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen169
\pgf@picminy=\dimen170
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen171
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen172
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen173
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen174
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen175
\pgf@xx=\dimen176
\pgf@xy=\dimen177
\pgf@yx=\dimen178
\pgf@yy=\dimen179
\pgf@zx=\dimen180
\pgf@zy=\dimen181
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen182
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen183
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen184
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen185
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfpic=\box57
\pgf@hbox=\box58
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box59
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count288
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen186
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen187
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen188
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen189
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen190
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@max=\dimen191
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count289
\pgf@shadingcount=\count290
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box60
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex
File: pgfcorerdf.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box61
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen192
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen193
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen194
\pgffor@skip=\dimen195
\pgffor@stack=\toks39
\pgffor@toks=\toks40
)) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
 (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count291
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen196
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen197
\tikz@lasty=\dimen198
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen199
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen256
\tikz@lastmovetox=\dimen257
\tikz@lastmovetoy=\dimen258
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen259
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen260
\tikz@figbox=\box62
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box63
\tikz@tempbox=\box64
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box65
\tikztreelevel=\count292
\tikznumberofchildren=\count293
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count294
\tikz@fig@count=\count295
 (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count296
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count297
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count298
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count299
 (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/libraries/tikzlibraryexternal.code.tex (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
 (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2023-12-04 v1.26 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
\pdftexcmds@toks=\toks41
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atveryend package
with kernel methods
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzexternalshared.code.tex))
\openout3 = main.auxlock
 (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2024-05-08 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count300
Inserting `l3color' in `luaotfload.parse_color'.
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box66
)
No file main.aux.

\openout1 = main.aux
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 10.
(d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2023/04/13 v2.5m Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 10.
 (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msb on input line 10.
 (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
warning  (hyphenation): bad specification: [\directlua]:1: attempt to index a nil value (local 'props')
.
\@settodim #1#2#3->\setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {{#3}}
                                                  #2#1\@tempboxa \setbox \@t...
l.10 \begin{document}
                   
The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.


warning  (hyphenation): bad specification: [\directlua]:1: attempt to index a nil value (local 'props')
.
\@settodim #1#2#3->\setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {{#3}}
                                                  #2#1\@tempboxa \setbox \@t...
l.10 \begin{document}
                   
The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.


warning  (hyphenation): bad specification: [\directlua]:1: attempt to index a nil value (local 'props')
.
\@settodim #1#2#3->\setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {{#3}}
                                                  #2#1\@tempboxa \setbox \@t...
l.10 \begin{document}
                   
The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.


warning  (hyphenation): bad specification: [\directlua]:1: attempt to index a nil value (local 'props')
.
\@settodim #1#2#3->\setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {{#3}}
                                                  #2#1\@tempboxa \setbox \@t...
l.10 \begin{document}
                   
The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.


warning  (hyphenation): bad specification: [\directlua]:1: attempt to index a nil value (local 'props')
.
\@settodim #1#2#3->\setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {{#3}}
                                                  #2#1\@tempboxa \setbox \@t...
l.10 \begin{document}
                   
The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.

(d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count301
\scratchdimen=\dimen261
\scratchbox=\box67
\nofMPsegments=\count302
\nofMParguments=\count303
\everyMPshowfont=\toks42
\MPscratchCnt=\count304
\MPscratchDim=\dimen262
\MPnumerator=\count305
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count306
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks43
) (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 485.
 (d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
))
\openout3 = main.auxlock

===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'lualatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tikz/main-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"' ========

\openout3 = main.auxlock

./main.tex:12: Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'lualatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tikz/main-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'tikz/main-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'tikz/main-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.12 \tikz{\draw (0, 0) -- (1, 0);}
                                 
This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.



[1{d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./main.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-05-27>
 ***********
)

Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 15013 strings out of 475915
 100000,1977958 words of node,token memory allocated
 512 words of node memory still in use:
   6 hlist, 2 vlist, 2 rule, 2 glue, 4 kern, 1 glyph, 10 attribute, 55 glue_spec, 7 attribute_list, 2 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:102,3:25,4:10,5:29,6:2,7:42,8:2,9:32,11:1
 37186 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 35 fonts using 2103295 bytes
 102i,5n,101p,8358b,390s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
<d:/Applications/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman7-regular.otf>
Output written on main.pdf (1 page, 2553 bytes).

PDF statistics: 18 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 11 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 16 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)


Can you show the first few lines of the log file of your main document?

I cannot even compile the example, it dies before even getting to the start of the document. warning  (hyphenation): bad specification: [\directlua]:1: attempt to index a n il value (local 'props') . \@settodim #1#2#3->\setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {{#3}}                                                   #2#1\@tempboxa \setbox \@t...

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz The log have been put into the question.
